# FB Like Button Counter Keeps Disappearing

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

I have a page with a URL of http://mydomain.com/?abc=123
I also have another page at http://mydomain.com/about.html

Both pages have "Like It" buttons that reveal the counter.

About once a week, the page with the query string has the FB "Like It" counter disappear as though no one has liked it and you can be the first to like it. Once I click the "Like It" button, the counter reappears and stays on the site for about another week. (It's not a cookies issue because once the counter disappears it is gone from any machine hitting that page).

The static page referenced above -- about.html -- has never had the counter disappear.

I am concluding that the fact I have a query string representing my web page is the reason why the FB "Like It" button behaves the way it does.

Can anyone confirm that to be the case?
And if that is the case, and I change the web page from resolving via query string to resolving via static url, is there anyway to regain the counter value from its present setting? Or am I in a situation where I have to start counting over from zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I tried -- so far it is working:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=123456789012345&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fvideo%2F%3Fplay%3Dmovie_number_1&amp;send=false
```

I simply encoded the url where before I did not have it urlEncoded (see below)

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=123456789012345&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com/video/?play=movie_number_1&amp;send=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the same URL and other data in the both the Open Graph meta tags and the iFrame loading the like button.  The iframe code looks something like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=
```

Details on the Open Graph meta tags here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

And check that the tags are being read properly by the Facebook Linter:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

When you use any of the Facebook social controls the URL is indexed by Facebook and acts as a static unique identifier. If there are dynamic or changing elements within your URL these will void previous counters.

Comment: I think you are saying that the use of the query string is not the way to go with the FB counter.
I have one URL that is http://mydomain.com/video/?play=movie_number_1 and http://mydomain.com/video/?play=movie_number_2
They both show the same FB Like It counter for about a week and then the counter disappears until I hit the Like It button myself. Once I do that, the counter value comes back.

Comment: Are you able to post the URL of the page that's having problems?

Comment: P.S. this page was built over a year ago. Since then, FB deprecated the Like It button I was originally using so I needed to resort to the new Like It button and that's when the problem ensued.